# How to display live traffic camera in my web page?

Tags: html, google-maps, camera, google-api, pusher

**I need to display live traffic camera for specific place** (For example, Tel aviv Ayalon road).
I saw some examples but still cannot understand how to implement it.

Here is an example for what I need: By selecting location, there is a live road camera.

I’ve tried the following example: https://github.com/pusher/pusher-realtime-tfl-cameras and http://jsbin.com/mazaf/3/edit?html,js,console,output

Here is my code:

```
<html>
    <body>
    </body>
    <script src="https://js.pusher.com/4.1/pusher.min.js"></script>
<script>
     // Open a Pusher connection to the Realtime TfL Traffic Camera API
    var pusher = new Pusher("f1b8177ecbc7a66de0c7");

    var channel = pusher.subscribe("cameras");

    var tflURL = "http://tfl.gov.uk/tfl/livetravelnews/trafficcams/cctv/";

     // Listen for new updates
     channel.bind("cameras-update", function(cameras) {
         var camerasArr = cameras.split("|");
         console.log(tflURL + camerasArr[0] + ".jpg");
     });
</script>
</html>
```

**Here is my output:**

Pusher : State changed : initialized -> connecting
pusher.min.js:8 Pusher : Connecting : {"transport":"ws","url":"wss://ws-ap2.pusher.com:443/app/e38b1f2ff9c8c301319c?protocol=7&client=js&version=4.1.0&flash=false"}
pusher.min.js:8 Pusher : State changed : connecting -> connected with new socket ID 208.479900
pusher.min.js:8 Pusher : Event sent : {"event":"pusher:subscribe","data":{"channel":"my-channel"}}
pusher.min.js:8 Pusher : Event recd : {"event":"pusher_internal:subscription_succeeded","data":{},"channel":"my-channel"}
pusher.min.js:8 Pusher : No callbacks on my-channel for pusher:subscription_succeeded

But how can I see the live camera streaming?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should read Readme.md on https://github.com/pusher/pusher-realtime-tfl-cameras, mainly the code example at the bottom. This will only allow you to access TfL cameras in the London area, as these are all the API exposes. You'll need to find a source of live video from that street before you think about integrating it into your app.

Comment: "This will only allow you to access TfL cameras in the London area" - no problem, in the beginning I would like to show London area.

Comment: As you can see, I have already read Readme.md on https://github.com/pusher/pusher-realtime-tfl-cameras and tried the example.

Do I miss something?

Comment: `var channel = pusher.subscribe("cameras");
var tflURL = "http://tfl.gov.uk/tfl/livetravelnews/trafficcams/cctv/";

// Listen for new updates
channel.bind("cameras-update", function(cameras) {
  
  var camerasArr = cameras.split("|");
  console.log(tflURL + camerasArr[0] + ".jpg");
});`

Comment: Do you have full example that showing any camera stream?